# Jenkins master node incoming port number for slaves?

Tags: ubuntu, firewall, jenkins, ufw

I have a Jenkins version 2.8 master node running on Ubuntu 14.04 and my slaves node cannot connect to it unless I disable the firewall via `sudo ufw disabled`.

I have port 8080 already open so folks can view the web ui, but I can't figure out which port to open to allow the slaves to connect.

Comment: What jenkins version are you using?

Comment: You'll want to fix the JNLP port https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+CLI#JenkinsCLI-Connectionmechanism

Comment: @HBruijn - that did it.  Looked all over for something like that and couldn't find it!!!